# I'm trying to get a count of records from a related entity that match a criteria

Tags: iphone, core-data, count, one-to-many, predicate

I have an entity matches which has a related to-many entity sets. I want to get a count of how many sets have the attribute 'set_finished' set to YES for a particular match. I'm trying to do this with:

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY set_finished == YES"];
 NSUInteger numberOfFinishedSets = [[[match valueForKeyPath:@"sets"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate ] count];

The second line crashes with this error, which I don't understand. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thanks.

> 2010-12-20 13:17:13.814
>   DartScorer[2154:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet
>   filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x617fb20'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `filteredSetUsingPredicate:` instead of `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` since the object is a set, not an array.

Comment: Thanks. Of course! I'm not sure how I missed that! It's amazing how many times I can read something and not see the obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

_NSFaultingMutableSet is kind of an empty set (if you will print the set you will see that xcode prints the entity name but not its content. it does that because :

> Faulting reduces the amount of memory
>   your application consumes. A fault is
>   a placeholder object that represents a
>   managed object that has not yet been
>   fully realized, or a collection object
>   that represents a relationship:
>
> A managed object fault is an instance
>   of the appropriate class, but its
>   persistent variables are not yet
>   initialized. A relationship fault is a
>   subclass of the collection class that
>   represents the relationship. Faulting
>   allows Core Data to put boundaries on
>   the object graph. Because a fault is
>   not realized, a managed object fault
>   consumes less memory, and managed
>   objects related to a fault are not
>   required to be represented in memory
>   at all.

i think you should create a Set to hold the objects you want to filter, and then filter the array tou have created.

hope it helps
shani

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY set_finished == YES).@count"];  
NSUInteger numberOfFinishedSets = [[match valueForKeyPath:@"sets"] filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This will just return the count of how many objects there are instead of actually retrieving the objects from disk and counting them.

Comment: Have you tried this? filteredSetUsingPredicate returns a set, not a count

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the string YES in single quotes  "... 'YES' "

(assuming the field contains the strings 'YES' and 'NO' and not 1 | 0)